# FFMPEG Start 2 videos at the same time but hide one until the other is finished

Tags: ffmpeg

I have a generic intro sequence (no audio) and a main video clip. I want the audio from the main clip to play as the intro sequence is playing then the video to switch from the finished intro sequence to the main video. So almost like playing both videos at the same time but hiding one until the other is finished. Is this possible with ffmpeg? Almost like a send to back function for the video on the main clip (but keep it's audio rolling so it's in sync when it shows as the intro clip finishes).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like you want a J-cut. This can be done using the overlay filter.

```
ffmpeg -i main.mp4 -i intro.mp4 -filter_complex "[1][0]scale2ref[intro][base]; \
       [base][intro]overlay=eof_action=pass[v]" -map "[v]" -map 0:a -c:a copy out.mp4
```

The `scale2ref` filter ensures that the intro is the same resolution as the main video. Then the intro is overlaid on top of the main video, in sync, and vanishes when it ends, leaving the main video on display. The audio is copied over - no processing required.

Comment: I don't have scale2ref on my ffmpeg, do I need to re-compile with some additional params to enable it's usage?

Comment: It's part of regular ffmpeg but was added in Aug 2015. Preferably, get a recent binary or if you know that the intro is the same resolution as the main video, you can skip it. Then it should be `-filter_complex "[0][1]overlay=...`

Comment: just updating ffmpeg via homebrew and I'll try again thank you!

Comment: and no I'll definitely need it as both are different res and 25fps and 30fps

Comment: There's a semi-colon missing after the first mention of `[base]`.

Comment: It works fantastic thank you! Is there anyway to match vertical resolutions, but maintain the aspect ratio of the intro video and pad with black bars or similar? Basically my main video was recorded on an ultra wide monitor but the intro video is half the width.

Comment: For now I've resized the intro video before running your J-cut ffmpeg -i intro.mp4 -vf pad=2536:1080:308:0 intro-resized.mp4

Comment: The scale2ref filter uses the main video as reference, including for aspect ratio, so no. What could do is skip the `scale2ref` and use scale,pad beforehand: `-filter_complex "[1]scale=-1:1080,pad=2536:1080:308:0[intro];[0][intro]overlay=...`